# how to do non blocking accept() in Python?

Tags: python, sockets, nonblocking

I cannot use threads thus I want to write a server program that can be interrupted after a while:

```
d = show_non_modal_dialog("serving clients")
s = socket(...)
s.bind(...)
s.listen()
while (!user_pressed_cancel())
{
  s.accept() # timed accept for like 1 second
  if timed_out:
    continue
  serve_client
  close_client_sock
}
hide_non_modal_dialog(d)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a non-blocking socket and call accept on that.

```
s.setblocking(0)
```

You could also set a timeout for blocking socket operations

```
socket.settimeout(value)
```

There also seems to be an issue in your code

accept() returns a (conn, address) pair value. so your code should have been

```
conn, address = s.accept()
```